# Group rows of a pandas Series or DataFrame when rows can belong to multiple groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

The `groupby` method of pandas is great when items/rows of a `Series`/`DataFrame` object each belong to one group. But I have a situation where each row can belong to zero, one, or multiple groups.

An example with some hypothetical data:

```
+--------+-------+----------------------+
| Item   | Count | Tags                 |
+--------+-------+----------------------+
| Apple  |     5 | ['fruit', 'red']     |
| Tomato |    10 | ['vegetable', 'red'] |
| Potato |     3 | []                   |
| Orange |    20 | ['fruit']            |
+--------+-------+----------------------+
```

According to the Tags column, Apple and Tomato both belong to two groups, Potato belongs to no groups, and orange belongs to one. So grouping by the tags and summing the count for each tag should give:

```
+-----------+-------+
| Tag       | Count |
+-----------+-------+
| fruit     |    25 |
| red       |    15 |
| vegetable |    10 |
+-----------+-------+
```

How can this operation be done?

Comment: Thanks @asynts, I accidentally used an old version of the source table. Edited to fix.

Answer (score 2):

#### explode your `'Count'` column by lengths of `'Tags'`

```
df.Count.repeat(df.Tags.str.len()).groupby(np.concatenate(df.Tags)).sum()

fruit        25
red          15
vegetable    10
Name: Count, dtype: int64
```

---

#### `numpy.bincount` and `pandas.factorize`

```
i, r = pd.factorize(np.concatenate(df.Tags))
c = np.bincount(i, df.Count.repeat(df.Tags.str.len()))

pd.Series(c.astype(df.Count.dtype), r)

fruit        25
red          15
vegetable    10
dtype: int64
```

---

#### Generic solution

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

counts = [5, 10, 3, 20]
tags = [['fruit', 'red'], ['vegetable', 'red'], [], ['fruit']]
d = defaultdict(int)

for c, T in zip(counts, tags):
  for t in T:
    d[t] += c

print(pd.Series(d))
print()
print(pd.DataFrame([*d.items()], columns=['Tag', 'Count']))

fruit        25
red          15
vegetable    10
dtype: int64

         Tag  Count
0      fruit     25
1        red     15
2  vegetable     10
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about the repeat function. The column I was grouping by in actuality wasn't strings, but this looks like it could be adapted.

Comment: I'll just caution that these solutions are somewhat specific to the simple example in the question. I tried to make my groupby_many answer more general, so you can use it if the values to group by aren't a column in the DataFrame, and since it returns a GroupBy object you can aggregate multiple columns of the DataFrame.

Comment: Every question carries with it a level of specificity.  You can generalize everything.  When asking or answering a question, you need to frame it to a specific problem such that it can be answered (somewhat) succinctly.  I would put the onus on you to clarify in your question the precise level of generality you require.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by writing a function I called `groupby_many`. It works on both `Series` and `DataFrame` objects:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def groupby_many(data, groups):
    """
    Groups a Series or DataFrame object where each row can belong to many groups.

    Parameters
    ----------
    data : Series or DataFrame
        The data to group
    groups : iterable of iterables
        For each row in data, the groups that row belongs to.
        A row can belong to zero, one, or multiple groups.

    Returns
    -------
    A GroupBy object    
    """ 
    pairs = [(i, g) for (i, gg) in enumerate(groups) for g in gg]
    row, group = zip(*pairs)
    return data.iloc[list(row)].groupby(list(group))
```

It works by creating a version of the data where each row is duplicated *n* times, where *n* is the number of groups the row belongs to. Each row in that version belongs to just one group, so it can be now handled by the regular `groupby`.

To see it in action on the sample data in the question:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
            'Item': ["Apple", "Tomato", "Potato", "Orange"],
            'Count': [5, 10, 3, 20],
            'Tags': [['fruit', 'red'], ['vegetable', 'red'], [], ['fruit']]})
>>> df = df.set_index('Item')
>>> print(df)

        Count              Tags
Item                           
Apple       5      [fruit, red]
Tomato     10  [vegetable, red]
Potato      3                []
Orange     20           [fruit]

>>> result = groupby_many(df, df['Tags']).sum()
>>> print(result)

           Count
fruit         25
red           15
vegetable     10
```